# How to aggregate values multiple from multiple points along a route as an attribute of it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, routing, analysis, network-analyst

I have a route network with a "Name" field that identify every route. On the other hand I have a shapefile of points. Each point corresponds to the number of people using a route at a time t. I would like to apply those counts to the routes but I do not know which tool to use, knowing that some routes have more than one count along them.

I have interpolated using the inverse distance weighing but it is giving values over the entire areas instead of just along the trails. I also tried to use calibrate routes but it does not seem to be working.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can the points be related to their respective routes in another way besides spatially?

Comment: Do all the points fall precisely along the lines or are they near the lines they need to be assigned to?  If the former, check out spatial joins. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000

Comment: Are you able to provide a diagram to help describe your input situation and desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a route is a single polyline and you can have multiple points along it for any given time then one method is:

1. Use spatial Join geo-processing tool with closest relationship and "one to many" set.
2. Run summary stats tool grouping by route ID and summing the count field.
3. Join the summary stats table back to the route layer by route ID.